# tensorflow 2.x distributed cluster

Tags: tensorflow, server, cluster-computing, tensorflow2.0, distributed-computing

I have been trying to distribute my model on different servers of a cluster using TF_CONFIG. 
However, all the resources I found use tensorflow 1.x method

```
import tensorflow as tf


cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"local": ["localhost:2222", "localhost:2223"]})

x = tf.constant(2)


with tf.device("/job:local/task:1"):
    y2 = x - 66

with tf.device("/job:local/task:0"):
    y1 = x + 300
    y = y1 + y2


with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    result = sess.run(y)
    print(result)
```

How can I do in tensorflow 2.x without tf.Session?